# special characters in contact form

Tags: php, special-characters, contact-form

I have this contact form and the problem is I dont get special characers in my mail (šđžćč or ÀÁÂÃÄÅ...).

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" />
<label for="City">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="City" />
<label for="Email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" />
<label for="Message">Message:</label>
<textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

contactengine.php:

```
<?php
$EmailFrom = "example@example.com";
$EmailTo = "example@example.com";
$Subject = "subject";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$City = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "City: ";
$Body .= $City;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
?>
```

I have searched on internet for solution but didn't find any that resolved my problem.
Does someone know what code do i have to insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripslashes()` breaks UTF-8 special characters.

I think you'd better set all `magic_quotes_*` to off in your php.ini (they add a lot of "useless" slashes) .

Comment: Thnx for the answer, Im new in php so I dont know what is stripslashes().

Comment: I removed stripslashes(). Now its $Email = $_POST['Email'];. But I dont get special characters

Comment: Right, you have to set your email encoding to UTF-8 too...
Add this to your 4th argument : `"From: <$EmailFrom>\r\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"` . Should be ok...