# HTML MAILTO not working correctly (äöü not transmitted correctly to outlook)

Tags: html, outlook, mailto, utf

When I write the letters "üäö" into my form and press submit there's "Ã¼ Ã ¤Ã" in outlook instead. Whats wrong with my code. I defined UTF-8 in my head. What else to solve this?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Bestellungen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
</head>

<body id="main_body" >  

<form action="MAILTO:mail@mail.ch?subject=DeinBetreff" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this yet but this should work for you:

**UPDATE:**

Tested and worked.

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130352/special-characters-in-contact-form)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" />
<label for="City">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="City" />
<label for="Email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" />
<label for="Message">Message:</label>
<textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$EmailFrom = "example@example.com";
$EmailTo = "example@example.com";
$Subject = "subject";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$City = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "City: ";
$Body .= $City;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>\r\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem comes from HTML.

Indeed, HTML have a problem with special characters.

use that : ü = &yacute , ä = &auml and ö = &ouml.

Comment: I can't use this. Because users have to fill out a form and they write with ü, ö, ä.. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: But what if they are User submitted? You can't ask the User to do that. Presumably OP needs some kind of string replacement via PHP?

Comment: I can't write PHP code into my file, because it's a .tpl which does not allow PHP code

Comment: ohhh ok , well, you need to create functions to store special characters.                                                                                                                             a (insert base) data encoding function
- Utf8_encode -> encoding special and international characters in utf8
- Htmlspecialchars (ENT_QUOTES) -> encoding HTML characters

a function of decoding data (recovery data base)
- Utf8_decode -> recovery of special and international characters for treatment
- Htmlspecialchars_decode (ENT_NOQUOTES) -> decode HTML characters except quotes and apostrophes

Comment: It would a really great help if you write an answer to my post with the exact code, I'm not really into PHP/HTML coding. So I don't get what you mean